# Creating an interactive map for my website?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps, interactive

I'd like to add an interactive map to my website, I will most likely be using the google maps API. My question: is it possible to have a user drop a pin on the map or enter an address and have that location saved to my database in order that it shows up for other users? also would you guys recommend any other maps APIs to make this easier? Thank you!!

Comment: drop a pin and save: possible; enter an address and save: when you wan't to get the coordinate for the address it's possible but not permitted

Answer (score 0):

You can have users interactively put pins on your map, or enter addresses to have that location saved to a database. But to load those items from your database, you'll have to develop your own API to handle that.

An alternative is to use [Google Fusion Tables](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/) as your database to save those points and bring in a [FusionTablesLayer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#FusionTables) to your map which loads all of the saved locations. One thing to note is that the addresses that are saved here will need to be Geocoded properly; Google has a [service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/) for that too!